# Azure ARM: Is a parent resource only complete after child resources complete?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

In the [ARM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-define-dependencies), it's clear that a child resource isn't implicitly dependant on the parent resource i.e. you need to add a dependsOn declaration.

However it isn't clear whether a parent resource is dependant on child resources implicitly i.e. do all the children need to complete before the parent is marked as complete?

Or is the child resource declaration simply for convenience to keep the names short i.e. so you don't need to specify the fully scoped name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent is not dependent on the child.  In some cases, the parent might not be very useful (e.g. vnet without subnets) but there is not inherent dependency.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense, when diagnosing tricky ARM issues it's good to know this exact nature.